# How to Count/Merge identical rows of data and add them in a column

Tags: vba, excel, merge, count

Lets say I have 10,000 rows of data, a sample shown below, where `H1` = `Header1`.

I'm trying to merge all identical columns and reflect that in the last column (Header6), ie I'm trying to add them all up, collapsing repeated rows. However, the difficulty I'm facing is that these (including header6) are text not numbers. Preferably using excel VBA (data must be in excel)

```
  H1      H2      H3      H4      H5      H6

  AA      BB      EE      HH      KK      1*
  AA      CC      EE      GG      KK      1*
  AA      CC      EE      GG      KK      1*
  AA      CC      EE      GG      KK      1*
  AA      DD      FF      HH      KK      1*
  AA      DD      FF      HH      KK      1*
```

The criteria is that all fields, `header1` to `header5` must be identical, and add it in `header6`. The result of this scenario should be as follows:

```
  H1      H2      H3      H4      H5      H6

  AA      BB      EE      HH      KK      1*
  AA      CC      EE      GG      KK      3*
  AA      DD      FF      HH      KK      2*
```

I tried many ways but to no avail. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: OK, we know the problem. But you need to show the code for solving together.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just create a Pivot Table and summarize by `count`? .... just a thouth ....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim Dic As Object, Cl As Range, i&, s$, key As Variant
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Cl In Range("A2:A" & i)
        s = Cl & "|" & _
            Cl.Offset(, 1) & "|" & _
               Cl.Offset(, 2) & "|" & _
                  Cl.Offset(, 3) & "|" & _
                Cl.Offset(, 4) & "|" & _
            Cl.Offset(, 5)
        If Not Dic.exists(s) Then
            Dic.Add s, 1
        Else
            Dic(s) = CLng(Dic(s)) + 1
        End If
    Next Cl
    Worksheets.Add
    i = 2
    [A1:F1].Value = Split("H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6", "|")
    For Each key In Dic
        Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "E")).Value = Split(key, "|")
        Cells(i, "F") = Dic(key)
        i = i + 1
    Next key
End Sub
```

**source**

[image]

**destination**

[image]